# Formatting a number with fixed number of significant digits

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I need a formatting function (say `format[x_, n_]`) which outputs numbers with fixed `n` *significant* digits without unnecessary dot. Examples:

```
format[.02,3] -> "0.0200"
format[.2,3] -> "0.200"
format[1,3] -> "1.00"
format[100,3] -> "100"    
format[1000,3] -> "100\[Times]10^1"
format[10000,3] -> "100\[Times]10^2"
```

Any ideas? The shorter - the simpler!

Comment: Some ideas about achieving both nice formatting and high interoperability can be found in the last part of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118381/280) answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here I present the scientific formatting function I have developed. It allows to restrict the displayed digits to only precise digits (negative and zero precision are also supported) and to specify the maximum number of zeros after the decimal point before converting the number to exponential form (negative values of this option are interpreted as the minimum number of digits before decimal point which will be showed). The option `PadSign` controls sign padding for positive numbers. The option `Align` allows to specify where the `\[AlignmentMarker]` should be placed inside of the number: before decimal point (`"."`), before first significant digit of the number (`"FirstDigit"`) or it should not be included in the output (any other value). The output is always wrapped in `Item` and the option `Alignment->"\[AlignmentMarker]"` is set when the `Align` is not switched off. It is also possible to pass any options of `Item` through `SciForm`.

Here is a demonstration of what is possible with `SciForm` (the code for generating this table see at bottom of this post):
[image: table1]

The code of `SciForm`:

```
ClearAll[SciForm];
Options[SciForm]=Join[Options[Item],{Align->"FirstDigit",PadSign->False}];
SyntaxInformation[SciForm]={"ArgumentsPattern"->{_,_.,OptionsPattern[]}};
SciForm::"sigz"= "In addition to `1` precise digit`3` requested, `2` zero`4` will appear as placeholder`4`.";
SciForm[x_?NumericQ,prec_Integer,thr_Integer:4,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
   Module[{rd,e=MantissaExponent[x][[2]],m1,m2,sign,mess,exp,i,al,alF},
      rd=If[prec>0,ToString/@RealDigits[Round[x,10^(-prec+e)],10,prec][[1]],{}];
      sign=If[Negative[x],"-",If[TrueQ@OptionValue[PadSign],ToString[Invisible["+"],StandardForm],""]];
      If[Head[alF=al=OptionValue[Align]]===List,al=First@alF;alF={"\[AlignmentMarker]",alF[[2]]},alF={"\[AlignmentMarker]",Center}];
      m1=If[TrueQ[al==="FirstDigit"],"\[AlignmentMarker]",""];
      m2=If[TrueQ[al==="."],"\[AlignmentMarker]",""];
      i=If[TrueQ[MatchQ[al,"."|"FirstDigit"]],
             Item[#,Alignment->alF,FilterRules[{opts},Options[Item]]]&,Item[#,FilterRules[{opts},Options[Item]]]&];
      exp[n_]:=ToString[Superscript["10",n],StandardForm];
      mess:=Message[SciForm::"sigz",prec,-thr-prec,If[prec>1,"s",""],If[-thr-prec>1,"s",""]];
      i@Which[
         e!=prec<=0,StringJoin[sign,m1,"0",m2,".?*",exp[e-prec]],
         e==prec<=0,StringJoin[sign,m1,"0",m2,".?"],
         0==e>=-thr,StringJoin[sign,"0",m2,".",m1,rd],
         0>e>=-thr,StringJoin[sign,"0",m2,".",Array["0"&,-e],m1,rd],
         0>=-thr>e,StringJoin[sign,"0",m2,".",m1,rd,"*",exp[e]],
         1<=-thr>e&&-thr<prec>=1,StringJoin[sign,m1,Insert[rd,{m2,"."},1-thr],"*",exp[e+thr]],
         1<=-thr==prec>e,StringJoin[sign,m1,rd,m2,"*",exp[e+thr]],
         1<=-thr>prec>e,mess;StringJoin[sign,m1,rd,Array["0"&,-thr-prec],m2,"*",exp[e+thr]],
         prec>e>0,StringJoin[sign,m1,Insert[rd,{m2,"."},e+1]],
         prec==e>0&&-thr<=prec,StringJoin[sign,m1,rd,m2],
         e==-thr>prec>0,mess;StringJoin[sign,m1,rd,Array["0"&,-thr-prec],m2],
         e>prec>0&&-thr<=prec,StringJoin[sign,m1,rd,m2,"*",exp[e-prec]],
         e>=prec>0&&-thr>prec,mess;StringJoin[sign,m1,rd,Array["0"&,-thr-prec],m2,"*",exp[e+thr]]
]];
```

The code for the above table:

```
data = {.0000000123456789, .000000123456789, -.00000123456789, \
-.0000123456789, .000123456789, .00123456789, .0123456789, .123456789,
    1.23456789, 12.3456789, 123.456789, 1234.56789, 12345.6789, 
   123456.789};
(*Note that NumberForm does not print Message although when called as \
NumberForm[123456.789,5] it does. Is it a bug? *)
Grid[Prepend[
  {SciForm[#, 4
      , Align -> "."
      , BaseStyle ->
       FontFamily -> "Times"],
     SciForm[#, 4, 5
      , BaseStyle ->
       FontFamily -> "Times"],
     SciForm[#, 4, -4
      , BaseStyle ->
       FontFamily -> "Times"],
     SciForm[#, 4, -1
      , BaseStyle ->
       FontFamily -> "Times"]} & /@ data,
  Item[#, Alignment -> "\[AlignmentMarker]", 
     BaseStyle -> {10, Bold}] & /@ {
    "SciForm[\[AlignmentMarker]#,4\[IndentingNewLine],Align\[Rule]\".\
\"\[IndentingNewLine],BaseStyle\[Rule]\[IndentingNewLine]FontFamily\
\[Rule]\"Times\"]&",
    "SciForm[#\[AlignmentMarker],4,5\[IndentingNewLine],Align\[Rule]\"\
FirstDigit\"\[IndentingNewLine],BaseStyle\[Rule]\[IndentingNewLine]\
FontFamily\[Rule]\"Times\"]&",
    "SciFor\[AlignmentMarker]m[#,4,-4\[IndentingNewLine],Align\[Rule]\
\"FirstDigit\"\[IndentingNewLine],BaseStyle\[Rule]\[IndentingNewLine]\
FontFamily\[Rule]\"Times\"]&",
    "SciFor\[AlignmentMarker]m[#,4,-1\[IndentingNewLine],Align\[Rule]\
\"FirstDigit\"\[IndentingNewLine],BaseStyle\[Rule]\[IndentingNewLine]\
FontFamily\[Rule]\"Times\"]&"}
  ], Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Automatic, Center}]
```

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Maybe you will find interesting this [related Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27313/5478)

Answer (score 22):

You probably need to read tutorial [**Output Formats for Numbers**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OutputFormatsForNumbers.html), but long story short, you are looking for [**NumberForm**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html)

```
NumberForm[N[Pi], 10]
```

> 3.141592654

Main thing is controlling number of precise digits and the number of digits to the right of the decimal:

```
NumberForm[1.23456, {3, 4}]
```

> 1.2300

Cool things you can also do:

```
NumberForm[30!, DigitBlock -> 5, NumberSeparator -> " "]
```

> 265 25285 98121 91058 63630 84800 00000

```
NumberForm[1234567890., 10, ExponentStep -> 6, NumberMultiplier -> "*"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's not so easy to achieve your goal, because `NumberForm` always wants a number `n` of digits to precision or a pair `{totaldigits, digits-after-decimal-point}`. So we must use `PaddingForm` or `Row` to do it. The solution isn't very short then. But the following code seems to work:

```
Clear[format]
Options[format] = Options[NumberForm];
format[x_, sd_] := 
 Module[{m, e, man, exp, num, n, f}, {m, e} = MantissaExponent[x];
  If[Abs[x] <= 10^-sd,
   Row[{PaddedForm[10 m, {sd, sd - 1}], Superscript["\[Times]10", e - sd + 2]}],
   If[e < sd,
    n = sd - e - 1; f = sd - e;
    If[n == 0, PaddedForm[x, {sd, f}], PaddedForm[x, {n, f}]], 
    If[sd == e, PaddedForm[x, sd],(*else sd<e*)
     Row[{Round[10^sd m, 10^-sd], 
       Superscript["\[Times]10", e - sd]}]]]]]
```

For your examples you will get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**
Replacing the `Numberform`, in `If[n==0,...]` with `PaddedForm[x,{sd,f}]` seems to work for the cases, which the old routine failed, as Alexey Popkov mentioned in his comment.

**Update 2**

Seems to work now for numbers smaller than `10^-sd`.

Comment: Thank you. But for some cases your function still gives wrong result: `format[10, 3]` gives `10` instead of `10.0`.

Comment: Another case: `format[.00000002, 3]` should give `"2.00\[Times]10^-8"`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov This case seems to work now after Update 2.

Answer (score 3):

In a similar case I used a combination of `NumberForm` and `AccountingForm`

ie:

```
AccountingForm[NumberForm[fn[i, j], {16, 16}]]
```

to get 16 digits

I get this:

> 0.0681758870688004

instead of this:

> 0.0681759

Answer (score 1):

```
mestLevo[x_] := Last[RealDigits[N[x]]];

SigMest[x_, n_] :=
  If[n == 0,
    Round[x] // N,
    Round[x 10^-mestLevo[x] 10^n] 10^-n 10^mestLevo[x]] // N;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not produce the required output as described in the question.