# Grid - Item - Alignment to decimal problem

Tags: bugs, grid-layouts, alignment

---

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 13.1**

---

I've run into a `Grid` layout problem for which I don't know a solution.  I want to specify alignment to a specific character such as a decimal *and* an `ItemSize` on a per-`Item` basis.  When I try to do this the decimal ends up on the right edge of the field rather than somewhere in the middle.  My application is part of a larger, more complex Grid layout but here is a simple illustration:

```
gridIt[itemopts__] :=
 Module[{x},
  x = {{1.234, 12.34}, {123.4, 1234.}, {1234, 1.234}};
  x = Map[Item[#, itemopts] &, x, {2}];
  x = Prepend[x, {"Title", SpanFromLeft}];
  Grid[x, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All]
 ]

gridIt[Alignment -> "."]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
gridIt[Alignment -> ".", ItemSize -> 4.4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why does this happen and how can I work around it?

Comment: One possible workaround is to use the `Alignment -> \[AlignmentMarker]` option and embed the `\[AlignmentMarker]` in the numbers as I showed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9015/280).

Comment: @Alexey would you please consider posting that as an answer, and including an example?

Comment: How about -- and this is ugly -- if you converted to strings and padded a fixed distance from the decimal point with whitespace? ...assuming you don't want to just pad right with zeros.

Answer (score 4):

This is messy:

If made the numbers strings and padded with whitespace:

```
padded[x_, cutoff_: 6] := Module[{tmp1, tmp2},
  tmp1 = StringSplit[ToString[x], "."];
  If[Length[tmp1] == 2,
   tmp2 = StringTake[tmp1[[2]] <> "      ", cutoff];
   tmp1[[1]] <> "." <> tmp2,
   tmp1[[1]] <> StringTake["       ", cutoff + 1]
   ]
  ]
```

I've made the cut off 6 because the default print precision is 6 so default you'll have at most 6 characters after the decimal place.

So now the revised gridIt:

```
ClearAll[gridIt];

gridIt[cutoff_, itemopts : OptionsPattern[{Grid}]] := Module[{x},
  x = Map[padded[#, cutoff] &, {{1.234, 12.34}, {123.4, 
      1234.}, {1234, 1.234}}, {2}];
  x = Map[Item[#, itemopts] &, x, {2}];
  x = Prepend[x, {"Title", SpanFromLeft}];
  Grid[x, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All]]

gridIt[6, Alignment -> {Right, Center}]

gridIt[2, Alignment -> {Right, Center}, ItemSize -> 5]
```

[image]

As you shrink the item size you need to reduce the cut off value.

This is all a bit clumsy but may do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Give items more space on the right, set Spacings explicitly:

```
gridIt[itemopts__] := 
 Module[{x}, x = {{1.234, 12.34}, {123.4, 1234.}, {1234, 1.234}};
  x = Map[Item[#, itemopts] &, x, {2}];
  x = Prepend[x, {"Title", SpanFromLeft}];
  Grid[x, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All, 
   Spacings -> {{2 -> 6, 3 -> 6}, Automatic}]]

gridIt[Alignment -> ".", ItemSize -> 4.4]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but that has way too much white-space.  What can be done?

Comment: Yeah, I was also unsatisfied with it. That spacing spec puts white space on both sides of a divider. Not sure if we can do it on 1 side. Maybe compensate somehow with ItemSize - differently for left and right columns?

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely a bug in `Grid`. Here is a workaround:

```
format[x_?NumericQ, spaces : {left_: 5, right_: 5}] := 
 MapAt[Row[{Spacer[left], #, Spacer[right]}] &, 
  SciForm[x, 4, -2, Align -> "."], 1]

Module[{x}, x = {{1.234, 12.34}, {123.4, 1234.}, {1234, 1.234}};
 x = Map[format[#, {7, 7}] &, x, {2}];
 x = Prepend[x, {Item["Title", Alignment -> Center], SpanFromLeft}];
 Grid[x, Alignment -> {Automatic, Center}, Dividers -> All]]
```

[image: table]

The `SciForm` function is from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9015/280).

Comment: I momentarily upvoted this, but when I try to use `ItemSize` it still breaks.  Could you please show how I am supposed to control absolute cell width?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In the `format` function you should change the values `5` in `Spacer[5]`. It is the way to control absolute cell width.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I updated the `format` function.

Comment: Alexey, the problem then is that it is *relative* width, or more specifically width + X spacing (margin).  Suppose elements in the left and right columns are not the same lengths, but I want the columns to have the same absolute width.  In this case I cannot use a fixed spacing, I need an `ItemSize`.  Do you see what I am fighting with?  Please know that I do appreciate your effort on this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately, at the moment I do not see any way to create a "normal" `ItemSize` or fix the bug. Only this not too easy-to-use workaround. But I am very interested in a solution or proper fix too. I think WRI must fix this really annoying problem.

Comment: Alexey, on an unrelated matter, would you mind if I asked to have [this question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5814164/618728) migrated here?  I'd now like to ask the same question myself, and I can either post my own or have this one migrated; your call.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have nothing against the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work as a workaround?

```
gridIt[itemopts__] := 
 Module[{x}, x = {{1.234, 12.34}, {123.4, 1234.}, {1234, 1.234}};
  x = Map[Item[#, itemopts] &, x, {2}];
  Column[{"Title",
    Grid[x, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All]
    }, Dividers -> {True, {True}}, Spacings -> {-0.1, {0.5, 0.2}}, 
   Alignment -> Center]]
```