# Decimal alignment in a grid

Tags: syntax, formatting, grid-layouts

I tried to find an answer and found quite a few posts on similar topics, but none of them really helped me. Here is a typical example:

```
a = 1;
b = 12.345;
c = 123.45;
list = {a, b, 
  c}; Grid[{{"test test test test", "test test test test", 
   "test test test test"}, list, 10 list, 100 list}, 
 Frame -> {All, {Red}}, 
 Alignment -> {".", 
   Automatic, {{{2, -1}, {1, 1}} -> Right, {{1, 1}, {2, -1}} -> 
     Center}}, Background -> {None, {None, {LightGray, LightGreen}}}]
```

It looks like the decimal point alignment shifts the columns as far to the right as possible, so it's a bit like a combination of `Right` and `"."` alignment. I guess what I want is a combination of `Center` and `"."` alignment. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Alignment to a character has bugs: [(13347)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13347/121)