# Problem with Alignment in Grid

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

Further to the problem noted in [Grid - Item - Alignment to decimal problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/grid-item-alignment-to-decimal-problem) I feel that the Alignment below should be decimal for the lower right and centre for the left and top headings. You will note that the top headings have also been decimal aligned.

```
heads = "head_" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[4];
cols = "col_" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[4];
data = Join[{Join[{"Table Name"}, heads]}, Join[{#},
             RandomReal[{-5, 20}, 4]] & /@ cols];

Grid[data, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray],
     Background -> {Yellow, 1 -> LightGray, 1 -> LightGray},
     Alignment ->  {".",    1 -> Center,    1 -> Center.  }]
```

You will note that the `Alignment` entries mimic the `Background` entries but the result is not satisfactory. The "head_1" is not center aligned but has also been aligned on the decimal point.

[image]

I have been searching for a solution to this without success and so a solution would be most welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap row and column headers with `Item` and use the option `Alignment -> Center`:

```
heads = Item["head_" <> ToString[#], Alignment -> Center] & /@ Range[4];
cols = Item["col_" <> ToString[#], Alignment -> Center] & /@ Range[4];
data = Join[{Join[{"Table Name"}, heads]}, Join[{#}, RandomReal[{-5, 20}, 4]] & /@ cols];

Grid[data, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray], 
 Background -> {Yellow, 1 -> LightGray, 1 -> LightGray}, 
 Alignment -> {"."}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much. I was exploring Item for use in colourising the data. It didn't occur to me that I could use that for overriding alignment as well. Although this works for alignment of the headings, you may notice when studying the picture that the column widths and positioning of the numbers are not quite right.