# Align 1st row of Grid different from the other rows

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

The grid formed below aligns its columns as I want on the decimal point:

```
x = 2. Pi/24 Range[0, 5];
data = Transpose[{x, Chop@Sin[x]}];

Grid[data, Alignment -> {"."}]
```

[image: Grid with columns aligned on decimal point]

Now I want to prepend a row to the grid with its two items centered. I tried the following, which if I understand the documentation, ought to do it:

```
Grid[Prepend[data, {"x", "sin x"}], Alignment -> {Center, {"."}}]
```

[image: Grid with header row, original rows misaligned]

But that just centers all entries in each column.

How do I get just the first row's entries to be centered but the remaining rows to be aligned on the decimal point?

Answer (score 4):

This should do it.  In `Alignment` docs under Generalizations & Extensions.

```
Grid[Prepend[data, {"x", "sin x"}],
 Alignment -> {".", Automatic, {{1, 1} -> Center, {1, 2} -> Center}}]
```

There is an odd `ItemSize` issue in the first column though, stemming from the `"."` alignment algorithm as I recall.  E.g.

```
x = 2. Pi/24 Range[0, 5];
data = Transpose[{x, Chop@Sin[x], Chop@Cos[x]}];

Grid[Prepend[data, {"x", "sin x", "cos x"}],
 Alignment -> {".", Automatic,
   {{1, 1} -> Center, {1, 2} -> Center, {1, 3} -> Center}},
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Does what I want, although ugly with the several table coordinate pairs required! Is there a way that uses the "recycling" of alignment specs?

Comment: I had a look at that but couldn't get it working.  I use coordinate pairs for cell background colours and usually have a some kind of map function to build the coordinate expression.

Comment: Cycling works for columns, e.g. `Grid[ReplacePart[Array["x"&, {10,6}], {#,#}->"---------" &/@Range[6]], Alignment->{{Center, {Right, Left}, Center}}, Frame->All]`

Comment: Yes the example is in Generalizations & Extensions for Alignment.  But why is the "Automatic" necessary?

Answer (score 3):

The following, using `Item` as suggested in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180225/148, does what I want, although I'd still prefer a simpler way using the spec recycling aspect of `Alignment` to avoid `Item`.

```
hdr = Item[Text[#], Alignment -> Center] & /@ {"x", "sin x"}; Grid[
 Prepend[data, hdr], Alignment -> "."]
```

[image: Properly aligned grid]