# Grid with data vertically aligned on the decimal point are not properly displayed in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, grid-layouts, wolfram-cloud, alignment, output-formatting

I can't align colum data on the decimal point:

```
data = { {1, 45000.5, 27500.}, {2, 22500., 18333.3},
         {3, 15000., 13750.}, {4, 11250., 11000.},
         {5, 9000., 9166.67} }

Grid[data, {Alignment->".", Frame-> All}]
```

Here is a screen capture of the result as seen in the Notebook:

[image]

I tried many syntax variations for the [`Alignment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alignment.html) option. And I also tried [`TextGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextGrid.html) instead of a plain [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) and [`TableForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) alongside [`TableAlignements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableAlignments.html). I never obtained a table whose values are aligned on the decimal point.

```
TableForm[data, TableAlignments->"."]
Grid[data, {Alignment->".", Frame-> All}]
Grid[data, {Alignment->{".","."}, Frame-> All}]
Grid[data, {Alignment->{{".","."}}, Frame-> All}]
```

I saw a [seven-years-old question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/grid-item-alignment-to-decimal-problem) that states there is an issue with alignment to the decimal point. But as far as I understood it, this is only triggered when using `ItemSize`. Not when using `Alignment` only.

<strike>Explicitly using a NumberForm and Right aligning the data is kind of a workaround, but this is not entirely satisfying.</strike>

Any thoughts or suggestions to fix my issue?

---

It appears the issue is with the Notebook: when I export the result as an image, data are properly aligned:

[image]

How to ensure the table is properly displayed in the Notebook too?

FWIW, I'm using Wolfram Cloud in a Firefox 69.02 browser on Linux

Comment: Sylvain, I can't reproduce your problem in the desktop version of MMA (v12, Win10-64), so the problem seems to be with the cloud version only.

Comment: Thanks @Marco. Indeed it seems related to the Cloud Notebook and/or my Browser. I've added the relevant tag to the question. FWIW, exporting the table either as bitmap or PDF will display the data with proper alignment.

Comment: Grid alignment at characters is not supported in cloud notebooks yet, but coming soon (maybe Cloud 1.55 in 2020 Q1).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, wrapping the grid inside a [Rasterize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) function displays the table with proper formatting--at the expanse of making the result uneditable:

```
Rasterize[Grid[data, {Alignment->".", Frame-> All}]]
```

[image: text vs. rasterized version of output]

Comment: Yes, that would be an OK workaround for now. Just FYI, you can also convert a cell to an image using the cell gear menu (next to the cell bracket in cloud notebooks): `Convert to > Image`. You can also use the cell option `CloudRenderingMethod->"Bitmap"` to force rendering as a bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Jan.