# Built-in way to handle uncertainty in measurment and physical constants?

Tags: data, uncertainty

Is there a built-in or fairly *elegant* way to handle uncertainties in measurement data and/or physical constants?

For instance, the 2010 CODATA for the elementary charge is given as $\mathsf{1.602 176 565(35) \times 10^{19}}\textrm{ C}$, where the $(35)$ represents uncertainly of $\mathsf{0.000 000 035 \times 10^{19}}\textrm{ C}$.  Or, in my case the D2 transition in $^9Be^+$ $\nu = \mathsf{31928.7436(40) \times 10^{19}}\textrm{ cm}^{-1}$.

I want to not only specify the uncertainty, but carry it through equations and calculate resultant uncertainties.  I don't want to recreate my own system of doing this if there are already functions and notation for doing this.

Comment: Sadly, no. There is this post ([Expression of uncertainty in measurement.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27107/5478)) but my answer is old, ugly and not full.

Comment: Maybe `Interval` will handle your needs on this? Also [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolvingMatrixSystemsWithRealIntervalOrUncertainElements/) might be useful. Same coauthor has [these](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/author.html?author=Valter%20Yoshihiko%20Aibe) as well, that might give a few ideas either from the basic principles or the underlying code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Mathematica 12, you can use the new [Around](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) function to deal with uncertainties and error propagation. You can even retrieve uncertainties in physical constants, like elementary charge:

```
Around@@Entity["PhysicalConstant", "ElementaryCharge"][{"Value","StandardUncertainty"}]
```

Outputting:

$1.60217663 (4 \pm  8 )\times 10^{-19}\text{C}$

Or you can define your own value such as the D2 line in your example:

```
\[Nu] = Around[31928.7436/Quantity[1, "Centimeters"], 
   0.0040/Quantity[1, "Centimeters"]]*10^19
```