# Tidy form of numbers with errors using ScientificForm

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, number-representation

Say I've computed something and got a number 0.02112398 with a computed error: 0.000331
Formatting it with `ScientificForm[0.02112398 \[PlusMinus] 0.000331]` gives me: $$ 2.1124 \times 10^{-2} \pm 3.31 \times 10^{-4} $$

How can I make it display it like this instead? (notice common exponent and the same number of digits)

$$ (2.1124 \pm 0.0331) \times 10^{-2} $$ 
having the option to cut some digits in both numbers would be a nice addition, for example displaying it like this:
$$ (2.11 \pm 0.03) \times 10^{-2} $$

Comment: Related: "[Expression of uncertainty in measurement.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27107/280)", "[Formatting a number with fixed number of significant digits](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8923/280)."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
PlusMinus[{x_, err_}] := 
 Module[{errE = Last@MantissaExponent[err], xE = Last@MantissaExponent[x]}, 
  Row[{"(", 
    NumberForm[N@Round[x, 10^(errE - 1)]*10^(-xE + 1), {xE - errE + 1, xE - errE}], 
    " \[PlusMinus] ", 
    NumberForm[N@Round[err, 10^(errE - 1)]*10^(-xE + 1), {1, xE - errE}, 
     ExponentFunction -> (Null &)], ")", 
    " \[Times] ", 
    DisplayForm@SuperscriptBox["10", ToString[xE - 1]]}]]
PlusMinus[x_, err_] := PlusMinus[{x, err}]
```

Now

```
PlusMinus@{0.02112398, 0.000331}
```

> [image: output]

or

```
0.02112398 ± 0.000331
```

> [image: output]

and after the last edit also

```
PlusMinus@{0.02112398, 0.0000000000331}
```

> [image: out2]

Comment: `PlusMinus@{0.02112398, 0.000331}` works well, but `PlusMinus@{0.2112398, 0.00331}` does not.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for pointing that out. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my take on this problem.

```
errorForm[num_, err_, digits_] :=
 Module[{exp, n, e},
  exp = Floor @ Log10 @ num;
  n = NumberForm[num/10^exp, digits, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)];
  e = NumberForm[err/10^exp, digits, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)];
  Row[{
    "(", n, "\[ThinSpace]\[PlusMinus]\[ThinSpace]", e, ")
    \[ThinSpace]\[Times]\[ThinSpace]", Superscript["10", exp]}]]

errorForm[2.1124*^-2, 3.31*^-4, 3]
```

> ```
> (2.11\[ThinSpace]\[PlusMinus]\[ThinSpace]0.0331)\[ThinSpace]*\[ThinSpace]10^-2
> ```

which looks this

[image: formatting]

in a *Mathematica* notebook.

#### Update

I have edited my function to deal with the issue raised by Mr.Wizard. Now

```
 errorForm[2.1124*^3, 3.31*^-3, 4]
```

produces

[image: formated]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I think I have fixed it.

Comment: I copied your answer into a Mathematica code block and then converted it to Input style, as you kindly suggested in [Meta1493](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/copy-code-block-from-se-to-mma-without-loss-of-line-breaks), and it introduced `\n` between the second and third lines of `Row`.  Great answer in any case (+1).

Comment: @bbgodfrey. Yes, that is an artifact of copy and paste. The code as written  in the original notebook doesn't have the problem. If I removed the line break between the last two lines of the `Module` above, copy and paste would work fine, but the answer would be harder to read. What to do? :-)

Comment: You can copy the `Row` code in Unicode format, and it fits on one line.  Although `\[ThinSpace]` then disappears from sight, it still is there and works when the code is copied back to Mathematica.  I tried it to be sure.

Comment: @bbgodfrey. But I really, really want readers to be able see all the special characters needed to get the formatting to look right. I think that's a very important feature of the answer.

Comment: You can (just barely) make it fit by replacing all but `\[ThinSpace]` by Unicode and replacing `"10"` by `10`:  `"(", n, "\[ThinSpace]±\[ThinSpace]", e, ")\[ThinSpace]×\[ThinSpace]", Superscript[10, exp]` with the opening `Row[{` and closing `}]`. on the preceding and following lines.

Answer (score 5):

Likely some duplication with existing answers but I felt like playing with this one.  I'll use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) so that the underlying representation does not change.

```
a_ ± b_ ± c_ := PlusMinus[a, b, c];

Format[b_?NumericQ ± err_?NumericQ ± acc_Integer: 6] ^:=
  Row[{
    "(",
     NumberForm[Row[{b, err}*10^-#, "±"], {acc, acc}, 
      ExponentFunction -> (Null &)],
    ")",
    Superscript["×\[ThinSpace]10", #]
  }] & @ ⌊Log10 @ Abs @ b⌋
```

Now with the default six digits of accuracy:

```
-0.02112398 ± 3.31*^-8
```

> ```
> (-2.112400 ± 0.000003) × 10^-2
> ```

Or only three:

```
-0.02112398 ± 3.31*^-8 ± 3
```

> ```
> (-2.110 ± 0.000) × 10^-2
> ```

The [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the last expression:

```
% // FullForm
```

> ```
> PlusMinus[-0.02112398`, 3.31`*^-8, 3]
> ```

This means that you can easily extract values or overload operations for `PlusMinus` as needed.

Comment: Great answer (+1), but it spills over into other open notebooks, even when they have different default contexts.  How can this prevented?  Also, could you add more explanation to your answer?

Comment: @bbgodfrey (1) This is defined upon a ``System` `` operator so it is global.  One could use a head besides `PlusMinus` at the expense of the pretty entry form.  (2)  I would be happy to but what would you like explained?

Comment: I am trying to understand the first line of your answer.  For instance, in a new notebook, `i_ ± j_ := i + 1` works, but `i_  := i + 1` does not.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The `PlusMinus` operator is [left-associative](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77925/121), therefore `a ± b ± c` is parsed as `PlusMinus[PlusMinus[a, b], c]` but I want to use and make a definition for the three parameter form `PlusMinus[a, b, c]`.  The definition `a_ ± b_ ± c_ := PlusMinus[a, b, c];` converts the former into the latter.  A definition requires an active head to attach the rule to; in `i_ ± j_ := i + 1` that head is `PlusMinus`; in `i_ := i + 1` you have a bare `Pattern` which is not something you can attach a rule to.

Comment: (+1) Notes: 1) Probably it is better to not show the exponent when it is zero; 2) You should apply `N` to  `{b, err}` in order to work with `_?NumericQ` correctly (`Integer`, `Rational` etc.).

Comment: @Alexey Thanks!  I'll see what I can do about that tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be close to what is wanted.

```
a1 = 0.02112398; a2 = 0.000331;
f[z1_, z2_] := Module[{t, ee = Floor[Log10[Abs[z1]]]}, 
                  t = NumberForm[z1 10^-ee, 3] ± NumberForm[z2 10^-ee, 3 + ee, 
                  ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]; t RawBoxes[SuperscriptBox[10, ee]]]
f[a1, a2]
```

$$ (2.11 \pm 0.03) 10^{-2} $$

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Now fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but seems close to what you seek:

```
myTidyForm[a_Real, b_Real] := (
   {"(" ~~ ToString[#[[1, 1]]] ~~ "\[PlusMinus]" ~~ 
       ToString[#[[2, 1]] 10^(#[[2, 2]] - #[[1, 2]])] ~~ ")\[Times]" ~~
        ToString[10]^ToString[#[[1, 2]]]} &@(MantissaExponent /@ {a, 
       b}))[[1]]
```