# How to format a number with an error?

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, formatting, number-representation

I'm having a surprising amount of difficulty in trying to format some numbers with errors. I can't find any previous attempts to do this here or elsewhere and it would surely be of use to the community.

I have some number-error pairs: `{12345.6789, 0.0012345}` which I would like to convert to strings with both the number and the error rounded to the same number of decimal places, such that the error has a precision of two significant figures.

```
f[{12345.6789, 0.03456}]
f[{12345.6789, 3.456}]
f[{12345.6789, 345}]
```

> "12345.679 ± 0.035"
>
> "12345.7 ± 3.5"
>
> "12340 ± 350"

I'm struggling to get this done with `RealDigits`, `N`, `NumberForm`, `StringRiffle` and others.

Can anyone produce a robust working implementation of `f`?

**Edit: Additional test cases**

There are quite a few subtly different behaviours when handling different number, including rounding, adding trailing zeros, handling precision = 0, and probably others. Therefore for the sake of comprehensively testing implementations here are a list of inputs and the required outputs (if you can think of any additional useful test cases then let me know / add them):

```
f[{12.3456, 0.0123}]     ->     "12.346 ± 0.012"
f[{12.3456, 0.123}]      ->     "12.35 ± 0.12"
f[{129.3456, 1.23}]      ->     "129.3 ± 1.2"
f[{-129.3456, 12.3}]     ->     "-129. ± 12."
f[{12.9999, 0.02}]       ->     "13.000 ± 0.020"
f[{1, 100}]              ->     "0 ± 100."
f[{-1, 100}]             ->     "0 ± 100."
f[{12345.6789, 345}]     ->     "12350. ± 340."
f[{12345.6789, 3456}]    ->     "12300. ± 3500."
```

Comment: It seems this is a duplicate: [Expression of uncertainty in measurement.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27107/5478) but your answer here is far superior so I'd mark the old one as a duplicate. Do you agree?

Comment: at 12.0 ,just use `Around`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update

This seems to do what you want a bit more simply than your own solution.

```
f[{a_, b_}] :=
  NumberForm[
    SetAccuracy[a ± b, Accuracy @ SetPrecision[b, 2]],
    ExponentFunction -> (Null &)
  ] // ToString // Quiet
```

Your test:

```
f[{12.3456, 0.0123}]
f[{12.3456, 0.123}]
f[{129.3456, 1.23}]
f[{-129.3456, 12.3}]
f[{12.9999, 0.02}]
f[{1, 100}]
f[{-1, 100}]
f[{12345.6789, 345}]
f[{12345.6789, 3456}]
```

> "12.346 ± 0.012"
>
> "12.35 ± 0.12"
>
> "129.3 ± 1.2"
>
> "-129. ± 12."
>
> "13.000 ± 0.020"
>
> "0. ± 100."
>
> "0. ± 100."
>
> "12350. ± 340."
>
> "12300. ± 3500."

Comment: Nice - you'd think this would be native by now though.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to get most of the way there. In a couple of cases the output is not quite as I would want, for example `f[{12.6789, 0.00123}]` -> `"12.6789 \[PlusMinus] 0.0012000000000000001"` and although the answer for `f[{12.9999, 0.02}]` is correct (`"13. \[PlusMinus] 0.02"`), I'd like to include the relevant trailing zeros, eg `"13.000 \[PlusMinus] 0.020"`. I'll have a proper look with this and @corey979's code later and try to form a fully robust solution, there are a lot of edge cases! Also the `345` being rounded to `340` I'm ok with, that's the normal banker's rounding of `Round`.

Comment: Thanks Mr.W, this works nicely. The only time I've spotted it fail is with an input along the lines of `{0,0.01}` which produces an output `"       -4\n0. \[Times] 10   \[PlusMinus] 0.010"`, however this is due to a failing in `NumberForm` ask discussed and circumvented here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133065/6588

Answer (score 6):

```
f[{a_, b_}, prec_] := 
 Block[{x = {a, b}, y}, y = SetAccuracy[x, prec]; 
  ToString @ y[[1]] <> " ± " <> ToString @ y[[2]]]

f[{12345.6789, 0.0012345}, 4]
```

> "12345.679 ± 0.001"

```
f[{12345.6789, 3.456}, 2]
```

> "12345.7 ± 3.5"

```
f[{12345.6789, 345}, 1]
```

> "12346. ± 345."

```
f[Round[#, 5]& @ {12345.6789, 345}, 1]
```

> "12345. ± 345."

Comment: I hadn't come across `SetAccuracy` before. I would want trailing zeros where needed, for example `f[{12345.6789, 0.0012345}, 4]` should be `"12345.6790 ± 0.0010"`. Also it struggles with some precisions, eg: `f[{12345.6789, 12.345}, 0]` comes out at a mess.

Comment: Then do `f[Round[#, 0.001] &@{12345.6789, 0.0012345}, 5]` - yields `"12345.6790 ± 0.0010"`. Rounding is one thing that can be done on the input itself; I focused on adressing the issue of **displaying given number of digits**. Also, [`SetAccuracy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAccuracy.html) is probably designed differently than what you think.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Mr.Wizard♦ 's answer I have come up with the following. I use `SetPrecision` to set the significant figures of the error to two (ala Mr.W). I then use `RealDigits`, which tells me about the number of significant figures either side of the decimal place, to calculate the necessary precision for the number, `a`. I can the use `SetPrecision` again, instead of `Round`, but I have to catch, using `If`, the cases where the required precision is $\le 0$.

I avoid using `InputForm` as I think this is what leads to the `0.0012000000000000001` problem. But I do use `NumberForm` to convert `1.*10^2` to `100.`. The `Quiet` is there to turn off the warning about the presence of trailing zeros - which I actually want!

My function:

```
f[{a_, b_}] := Module[{aa, bb, p},
  bb = SetPrecision[b, 2];
  p = Last[RealDigits[a]] - Last[RealDigits[bb]] + 2;
  aa = If[p > 0, SetPrecision[a, p], 0];
  Quiet[
   ToString@
    NumberForm[PlusMinus @@ {aa, bb}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)],
   {NumberForm::sigz}
   ]
  ]
```

This passes all the test cases I have outlined so far above, please let me know if you find any tests you think it fails. And obviously if you find a more elegant implementation!

```
f[{12.3456, 0.0123}]
f[{12.3456, 0.123}]
f[{129.3456, 1.23}]
f[{-129.3456, 12.3}]
f[{12.9999, 0.02}]
f[{1, 100}]
f[{-1, 100}]
f[{12345.6789, 345}]
f[{12345.6789, 3456}]
```

> "12.346 ± 0.012"
>
> "12.35 ± 0.12"
>
> "129.3 ± 1.2"
>
> "-129. ± 12."
>
> "13.000 ± 0.020"
>
> "0 ± 100."
>
> "0 ± 100."
>
> "12350. ± 340."
>
> "12300. ± 3500."

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I borrowed your use of `ExponentFunction` to replace the poorly chosen `InputForm`.

Answer (score 3):

This extends Mr. Wizard's answer to handle large/small numbers:

```
printNumberError[a_, b_] := 
 Block[{exponent = Floor[Log[10, Abs[a]]], 
    sas = SetAccuracy[#1, Accuracy[SetPrecision[#2, 2]]] &}, 
   If[exponent < 6 && exponent > -4, 
    NumberForm[sas[Row[{a, "±", b}, " "], b], 
     ExponentFunction -> (Null &)], 
    Block[{aa = a/10^exponent, bb = b/10^exponent}, 
     Row[{"(", sas[aa, bb], "±", sas[bb, bb], ")", 
       "×", Superscript[10, exponent]}, " "]]]];
```

For example:

```
printNumberError[-6.390809*10^-6, 3.4485*10^-8]
```

Gives:

$$(-6.391\pm0.034)\times10^{-6}$$

Comment: Good addition; thanks.  I suggest making the `SetAccuracy[a, Accuracy[SetPrecision[b, 2]]]` operation a function to reduce repetition in this code.  I can edit that in if you like.

Comment: Good point ... updated my code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ...  Also, I generally keep my Mma code in plain text (*.m) files so that I can use source control in a meaningful way.  Thus, special characters like $\pm$ are problematic.

Comment: There is a difference between "private" *Mathematica* characters and standard characters that *Mathematica* uses.  ± is part of the latter and it should work fine in plain text.  Have you actually experienced problems or did you assume it would not work?

Comment: I did a test and git (on Ubuntu) does handle both "±" and "×" without issue.