# ExponentFunction not respected in NumberForm when typesetting zero?

Tags: formatting, number-representation

Let's try to typeset a couple of numbers with a <s>precision</s> accuracy of 4:

```
0``4
1``4
1000000``4
```

[image]

I do not want the numbers returned with `*10^...` therefore I use `NumberForm` with `ExponentFunction` set to `Null`:

```
NumberForm[0``4, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
NumberForm[1``4, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
NumberForm[1000000``4, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
```

[image]

However as you can see, the 0 is still in exponent form...! It should be `0.000` much like the `1.000`.

A bug?

Any ideas on how to circumvent this behaviour?

Comment: I wonder if this hasn't been discussed before.  I'll see what I can find.  Thanks for pointing out this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a circumvent side, since [`ExponentFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExponentFunction.html)does return an exponent for 0 even after we asked not to do so, we can use the [`NumberFormat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberFormat.html) function to typeset it manually:

```
NumberForm[0``4,
 NumberFormat -> (If[#3 =!= "", StringJoin[{#1, Table["0", Abs@ToExpression@#3 - 1]}], #1] &),
 ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]

(* 0.000 *)
```

Note, this will work when you want [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accuracy.html) as shown in OP question (``), not [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) (`).

Comment: Thankfully I did indeed mean accuracy and not precision, your workaround works thanks! An odd edge case for `NumberForm`.