# Align table entries on decimal point and fix number of digits after decimal point

Tags: list-manipulation

I have:

```
f[t_] := 4 t^3 - 3; g[t_] := -t^3 + 2;
TableForm[
 Table[{t, f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 2, .5}],
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {t, x, y}},
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]

Is it possible to align each column on its decimal point? Further, is it possible to add zeros so that each number in the first column has one digit to the right of the decimal point, each number in the second column has one digit to the right of the decimal point and each number in the third column has three digits to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: Related: "[Formatting a number with fixed number of significant digits](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9015/280)."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
TableForm[
 Table[{NumberForm[t, {Infinity, 1}], NumberForm[f[t], {Infinity, 1}], 
  NumberForm[g[t], {Infinity, 3}]}, {t, 0, 2, .5}],
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {t, x, y}}, TableAlignments -> "."]
```

> [image]

Comment: A very nice answer. Just what I needed.